# Issue in Retrieving data from Table when it is having more than 1 records for 1 ID

Tags: join

I have a table ABC and it has 5 columns and now I need to find such records in the table for same ID value where the value in columns C is 0 in all the cases.

Solution please.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you group by the `ID` column, you can check that the min and max rows in the grouping for column `C` are the same and equal to 0, meaning that all rows for that `ID` are equal to 0 in that column. You can also check the `COUNT()` to verify there is more than 1 row for that `ID` like so:

```
SELECT ID
FROM ABC
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(C) = MAX(C)
    AND MIN(C) = 0
    AND COUNT(ID) > 1
```

Note, I used the `MIN(C) = MAX(C)` check instead of `SUM(C)` in case there's potential for negative numbers that ended up summing up with the positive numbers to 0, which would provide a wrong result.